Django context processor code not working
I am trying to use context_processors.py to show the number of unread_messages on my base.html message icon, but for some reason it is not working.
While the unread_message counter is working for the user_messages_view properly, it just won't work for base.html. I tried changing the logic of my context_processors.py, but same result.
So my models.py:
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='sent_messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='received_messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, related_name='messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Message from {self.sender} to {self.recipient} in {self.business}'

    @property
    def sender_is_business(self):
        return self.sender.business.exists()

    @property
    def recipient_is_business(self):
        return self.recipient.business.exists()

My views.py:
@login_required
def user_messages_view(request):
    businesses = Business.objects.filter(
        Q(messages__sender=request.user) | Q(messages__recipient=request.user)
    ).distinct()

    user_messages = []
    latest_messages = []

    for business in businesses:
        if request.user == business.seller:
            # Query messages for business with other users
            messages = Message.objects.filter(
                Q(sender=business.seller) | Q(recipient=business.seller)
            ).filter(business=business).order_by('-timestamp')
            for user, chat in itertools.groupby(messages, lambda m: m.recipient if m.sender == request.user else m.sender):
                last_message = next(chat)
                unread_count = Message.objects.filter(recipient=business.seller, sender=user, business=business, is_read=False).count()
                user_messages.append({
                    'business': business,
                    'last_message': last_message,
                    'user': user,
                    'unread_count': unread_count,
                })
                latest_messages.append(last_message)
        else:
            last_message = Message.objects.filter(
                Q(sender=request.user, recipient=business.seller) |
                Q(sender=business.seller, recipient=request.user)
            ).filter(business=business).order_by('-timestamp').first()
            unread_count = Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user, sender=business.seller, is_read=False).count()
            user_messages.append({
                'business': business,
                'last_message': last_message,
                'unread_count': unread_count,
            })
            latest_messages.append(last_message)

    # Sort user_messages by the latest message timestamp
    user_messages = sorted(user_messages, key=lambda um: um['last_message'].timestamp, reverse=True)
    
    unread_message_counter = sum(msg['unread_count'] for msg in user_messages)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        business_slug = request.POST.get('business_slug')
        business = get_object_or_404(Business, business_slug=business_slug)
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        if content:
            if request.user == business.seller:
                # Business sending message to user
                username = request.POST.get('username')
                if username:
                    recipient = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, username=username)
                    Message.objects.create(
                        sender=request.user,
                        recipient=recipient,
                        business=business,
                        content=content
                    )
                    return redirect(f'{request.path}?business_slug={business.business_slug}&username={recipient.username}')
            else:
                # User sending message to business
                Message.objects.create(
                    sender=request.user,
                    recipient=business.seller,
                    business=business,
                    content=content
                )
                return redirect(f'{request.path}?business_slug={business.business_slug}')

    selected_business = None
    selected_user = None
    messages = []
    if 'business_slug' in request.GET:
        business_slug = request.GET.get('business_slug')
        selected_business = get_object_or_404(Business, business_slug=business_slug)
        if request.user == selected_business.seller and 'username' in request.GET:
            # Query messages for selected_business with selected_user
            username = request.GET.get('username')
            if username:
                selected_user = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, username=username)
                messages = Message.objects.filter(
                    Q(sender=selected_user, recipient=selected_business.seller) |
                    Q(sender=selected_business.seller, recipient=selected_user)
                ).filter(business=selected_business).order_by('timestamp')
        else:
            messages = Message.objects.filter(
                Q(sender=request.user, recipient=selected_business.seller) |
                Q(sender=selected_business.seller, recipient=request.user)
            ).filter(business=selected_business).order_by('timestamp')

        Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user, business=selected_business).update(is_read=True)

    context = {
        'user_messages': user_messages,
        'selected_business': selected_business,
        'selected_user': selected_user,
        'messages': messages,
        'unread_message_counter': unread_message_counter,
    }
    return render(request, 'business/user_messages.html', context) 

My user_messages.html:
<main class="content mt-5 mb-5">
    <div class="container p-0">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3">Your Messages</h1>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-5 col-xl-3 border-right">
                    {% for message in user_messages %}
                        {% if message.user %}
                        {# Handle display user_messages for business with other users #}
                        <a href="{% url 'user_messages' %}?business_slug={{ message.business.business_slug }}&username={{ message.user.username }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0">
                            {% if message.unread_count > 0 %}
                                <div class="badge bg-success float-right">{{ message.unread_count }}</div>
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                                <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name={{ message.user.username }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" width="40px" height="40px">
                                <div class="flex-grow-1 ml-3">
                                    {{ message.user.username }}
                                    {% if message.last_message %}
                                    <div class="small {% if message.unread_count > 0 %}font-weight-bold{% endif %}">{{ message.last_message.content }}</div>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <p>No messages yet.</p>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        {% else %}
                        <a href="{% url 'user_messages' %}?business_slug={{ message.business.business_slug }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0">
                            {% if message.unread_count > 0 %}
                                <div class="badge bg-success float-right">{{ message.unread_count }}</div>
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                                <img src="{{ message.business.profile_picture.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" width="40px" height="40px">
                                <div class="flex-grow-1 ml-3">
                                    {{ message.business.business_name }}
                                    {% if message.last_message %}
                                    <div class="small {% if message.unread_count > 0 %}font-weight-bold{% endif %}">{{ message.last_message.content }}</div>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <p>No messages yet.</p>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    <hr class="d-block d-lg-none mt-1 mb-0">
                </div>
                {% if selected_business %}
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-7 col-xl-9">
                    <div class="py-2 px-4 border-bottom d-none d-lg-block">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center py-1">
                            {% if selected_user %}
                            {# Handle display selected_user #}
                            <div class="position-relative">
                                <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name={{ selected_user.username }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ selected_user.username }}" width="40" height="40">
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-grow-1 pl-3">
                                <strong>{{ selected_user.username }}</strong>
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            <div class="position-relative">
                                <img src="{{ selected_business.profile_picture.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ selected_business.business_name }}" width="40" height="40">
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-grow-1 pl-3">
                                <strong>{{ selected_business.business_name }}</strong>
                            </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="position-relative">
                        <div class="chat-messages p-4">
                            {% for message in messages %}
                            {% if message.sender == request.user %}
                            <div class="chat-message-right pb-4">
                                <div>
                                    {% if request.user == selected_business.seller %}
                                    <img src="{{ request.user.business.profile_picture.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ request.user.business.business_name }}" width="40" height="40">
                                    {% else %}
                                    <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="User Avatar" width="40" height="40">
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <div class="text-muted small text-nowrap mt-2">{{ message.timestamp }}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex-shrink-1 bg-light rounded py-2 px-3 mr-3">
                                    <div class="font-weight-bold mb-1">You</div>
                                    {{ message.content }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            <div class="chat-message-left pb-4">
                                <div>
                                    {% if selected_user %}
                                    <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name={{ selected_user.username }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ selected_user.username }}" width="40" height="40">
                                    {% else %}
                                    <img src="{{ selected_business.profile_picture.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ selected_business.business_name }}" width="40" height="40">
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <div class="text-muted small text-nowrap mt-2">{{ message.timestamp }}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex-shrink-1 bg-light rounded py-2 px-3 ml-3">
                                    {% if selected_user %}
                                    <div class="font-weight-bold mb-1">{{ selected_user.username }}</div>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <div class="font-weight-bold mb-1">{{ selected_business.business_name }}</div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {{ message.content }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% if request.user.is_authenticated and selected_business %}
                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'user_messages' %}?business_slug={{ selected_business.business_slug }}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="business_slug" value="{{ selected_business.business_slug }}">
                        {% if request.user == selected_business.seller and selected_user %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="{{ selected_user.username }}">
                        {% endif %}
                        <div class="flex-grow-0 py-3 px-4 border-top">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input name="content" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

My context_processors.py:
def unread_message_count(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        unread_count = Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user, is_read=False).count()
    else:
        unread_count = 0
    return {
        'unread_message_count': unread_count,
    }

My settings.py:
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'business.context_processors.unread_message_count',
            ],
        },
    },
]

My base.html:
                                <a href="{% url "user_messages" %}">
                                    <div class="max-md:hidden wishlist-icon flex items-center relative cursor-pointer">
                                        <i class="ph-bold ph-chats text-2xl"></i>
                                        <span class="quantity wishlist-quantity absolute -right-1.5 -top-1.5 text-xs text-white bg-black w-4 h-4 flex items-center justify-center rounded-full">{{ unread_message_count }}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>

All my other context processor counts are working except for this one. According to me, the unread_message_counter logic seems fine. I can't figure out why this won't work.

could you add a simple debug line in the context processor like this: print(f"unread_message_count: {unread_count}"). Just to check whether the context processor is actually being called and also to check whether the logic is ok.

Yes so after adding the line it shows me unread_message_count: 1 which is actually correct.

Is the template showing "0" next to the chat icon? or only showing the chat icon with no number? I would check if the {{ unread_message_count }} shows up without all the css styling on top of it.

I'd also suggest checking that your path to the context_processors file in the TEMPLATES is correct.

Yeah so the path is correct and the 0 is showing up with the chat icon.

Showing 0 implies the context_processor is working, but either the user isn't authenticated or they have no messages.
Check/print out the request.user and request.user.is_authenticated from within the context_processor function.
Is AUTH_USER_MODEL set to: 'users.CustomUser'?

Even when they have unread messages it shows 0. Yes AUTH_USER_MODEL is set to users.CustomUser in my settings.py.
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

I changed my code to:
def unread_message_count(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        unread_count = Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user, is_read=False).count()
        print(f"unread_message_count: {unread_count}")
        print(f"{request.user}")
        print(f"{request.user.is_authenticated}")
    else:
        unread_count = 0
    return {
        'unread_message_count': unread_count,
    }

It returns
unread_message_count: 3 john True
Still I get 0 above the message icon.

I'd move the print statement you added to the context_processor directly before the return statement. You can see if it's running more than one time per page load. Possibly, the template is rendering before it sets the request.user, or running more than once (returning 0 the second time?), or aggressive caching?

try to set the he context processor to return a dummy value of 2 unread messages.
business/context_processors.py
def unread_message_count(request):
# Return a dummy value to test the template integration
return {'unread_message_count': 2}
check if it displays the 2 unread messages. to know where the issue is.

When I do this it still shows 0.

Okay since my cart count was working I decided to put my cart count in place of the unread_message_count it still shows zero items in cart when I added one. So my logic is working just I don't know why it won't show the number.
